# request.user always returns AnonymousUser

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have created a django `model` which includes a foreign key to a user as follows:

```
from authentication.models import User
from django.db import models

class Event(models.Model):
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    dr_notice_period = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dr_duration = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dr_request = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

My `serializers.py` file is as follows:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['user', 'dr_notice_period', 'dr_duration', 'dr_request']
```

My `views.py` is as follows:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import status

from vpp_optimization.serializers import EventSerializer

@api_view(['POST'])
def event(request):

    serializer = EventSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        instance = serializer.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response({"status": "error", "data": serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

What I need to do is to go to a URL and login as a user. Then I need to go to another URL and add with POST request some details about the `event` and save the details as well as the `user` in the database. However after login and POST request I get the following error:

```
Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f7daf1469d0>": "Event.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

It seems that it always returns an AnonymousUser, although I have logged in. Any idea of how can I solve this issue?

The `settings.py` are the following:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': [
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

Comment: check whether your user is authenticated or not by printing like this `print(request.user.is_authenticated())`

Comment: @AnkitTiwari It returns False.

Comment: This means your user is not authenticated that is why you're getting that error try to authenticate your user

Comment: What's the default  authentication class you're using ? Can you share your settings also ?

Comment: @arjun I added the settings.py in the description.

Comment: See if https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#installation helps

Answer (score 0):

you will have to provide

```
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]  # DjangoModelPermissionsWithRead
```

in your views.

Edits.

everytime you access your views for any type of request you should pass token such as.

```
axios
  .get(
    `http://localhost:8000/anything`,
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
      },
    }
  )
```

edit 2 -

you are wrong importing your user, use this -

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

Comment: With this I get the following:  "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

Comment: check my edit, i have updated how to pass auentication credentials.

Comment: Where to put this?

Comment: I cannot understand where to use the first edit. Could you explain it?

Comment: whenever you are using frontend client like react or anything, you would be using axios or request  or something similar  to access your api endpoints. there you will have to provide token with each request. (from postman also if you use).